# Android Homescreen

Tags: android, viewflipper, launcher

Hey folks, this is my first post so go easy on me!

I want to develop an application where you can navigate through 7 or so screens like you can on the homescreen.

I have seen a few posts on this but I can't seem to get them to work, I also can't seem to add comments to them (I'm sure thats me being a noob)

So I need a working project so I can look at it and dissect it and use the bits relevant to me.

This one was of interest but I just can't get it to work.  I use Eclipse and the SDK is that what everyone else uses?

[Developing an Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen)

When I implement it I need to tell the app how to start because it installs it but says there is no activity.

hope you can help

T

What I have in my Main.Java

```
package com.matthieu.launcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class main extends Activity {

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Button onebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsone);
      onebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series1button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
         }
      });

      Button twobutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundstwo);
      twobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series2button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
         }
      });

      Button threebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsthree);
      threebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series3button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);           
         }
      });

      Button fourbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsfour);
      fourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series4button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
         }
      });

      Button fivebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsfive);
      fivebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series5button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
         }
      });

      Button sixbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundssix);
      sixbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series6button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
         }
      });

      Button sevenbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsseven);
      sevenbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series7button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);           
         }
      });

      Button eightbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundseight);
      eightbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series8button.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);           
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Then Dragablespace.java

```
package com.matthieu.launcher;

import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class DragableSpace extends ViewGroup {

   private Scroller mScroller;
   private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;

   private int mScrollX = 0;
   private int mCurrentScreen = 0;

   private float mLastMotionX;

   private static final String LOG_TAG = "DragableSpace";

   private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY = 1000;

   private final static int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
   private final static int TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING = 1;

   private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

   private int mTouchSlop = 0;

   public DragableSpace(Context context) {

      super(context);
      mScroller = new Scroller(context);

      mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();

      this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
   }

   public DragableSpace(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

      super(context, attrs);
      mScroller = new Scroller(context);

      mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();

      this.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

      TypedArray a=getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.DragableSpace);
      mCurrentScreen = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DragableSpace_default_screen, 0);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

      /*
       * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
       * If we return true, onTouchEvent will be called and we do the actual
       * scrolling there.
       */

      /*
       * Shortcut the most recurring case: the user is in the dragging state
       * and he is moving his finger. We want to intercept this motion.
       */
      final int action = ev.getAction();

      if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && (mTouchState != TOUCH_STATE_REST)) {
        return true;
      }

      final float x = ev.getX();

      switch (action) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            /*
             * mIsBeingDragged == false, otherwise the shortcut would have caught it. Check
             * whether the user has moved far enough from his original down touch.
             */

            /*
             * Locally do absolute value. mLastMotionX is set to the y value
             * of the down event.
             */
            final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);

            boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;

            if (xMoved) {
                // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Remember location of down touch
            mLastMotionX = x;

            /*
             * If being flinged and user touches the screen, initiate drag;
             * otherwise don't.  mScroller.isFinished should be false when
             * being flinged.
             */
            mTouchState = mScroller.isFinished() ? TOUCH_STATE_REST : TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Release the drag
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
            break;
    }

    /*
     * The only time we want to intercept motion events is if we are in the
     * drag mode.
     */
    return mTouchState != TOUCH_STATE_REST;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    }
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);

    final int action = event.getAction();
    final float x = event.getX();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "event : down");
            /*
             * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished
             * will be false if being flinged.
             */
            if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                mScroller.abortAnimation();
            }

            // Remember where the motion event started
            mLastMotionX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Log.i(LOG_TAG,"event : move");
            // if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            // Scroll to follow the motion event
            final int deltaX = (int) (mLastMotionX - x);
            mLastMotionX = x;

            //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "event : move, deltaX " + deltaX + ", mScrollX " + mScrollX);

            if (deltaX < 0) {
                if (mScrollX > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.max(-mScrollX, deltaX), 0);
                }
            } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                final int availableToScroll = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1)
                    .getRight()
                    - mScrollX - getWidth();
                if (availableToScroll > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                }
            }
            // }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "event : up");
            // if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            int velocityX = (int) velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

            if (velocityX > SNAP_VELOCITY && mCurrentScreen > 0) {
                // Fling hard enough to move left
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen - 1);
            } else if (velocityX < -SNAP_VELOCITY
                    && mCurrentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
                // Fling hard enough to move right
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
            } else {
                snapToDestination();
            }

            if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
            }
            // }
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "event : cancel");
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    }
    mScrollX = this.getScrollX();

    return true;
}

private void snapToDestination() {
    final int screenWidth = getWidth();
    final int whichScreen = (mScrollX + (screenWidth / 2)) / screenWidth;
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "from des");
    snapToScreen(whichScreen);
}

public void snapToScreen(int whichScreen) {         
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "snap To Screen " + whichScreen);
    mCurrentScreen = whichScreen;
    final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
    final int delta = newX - mScrollX;
    mScroller.startScroll(mScrollX, 0, delta, 0, Math.abs(delta) * 2);             
    invalidate();
}

public void setToScreen(int whichScreen) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "set To Screen " + whichScreen);
    mCurrentScreen = whichScreen;
    final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
    mScroller.startScroll(newX, 0, 0, 0, 10);             
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int childLeft = 0;

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + childWidth, child
                    .getMeasuredHeight());
            childLeft += childWidth;
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("error mode.");
    }

    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("error mode.");
    }

    // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "moving to screen "+mCurrentScreen);
    scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * width, 0);      
}  

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        mScrollX = mScroller.getCurrX();
        scrollTo(mScrollX, 0);
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Then my main.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.matthieu.launcher.DragableSpace xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.matthieu.launcher" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/space" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" app:default_screen="1">
   <include android:id="@+id/left" layout="@layout/left_screen" />
   <include android:id="@+id/center" layout="@layout/initial_screen" />
   <include android:id="@+id/right" layout="@layout/right_screen" />
</com.matthieu.launcher.DragableSpace>
```

I also have 3 other layout files called initial, left and right(_screen)

Comment: Did you add your Activity in the Manifest?

Comment: I couldn't actually see an activity to add it, I could create a separate one, but how would I link it to this code?

Comment: Alright, so based on what you said, I'm assuming that you have just 1 Activity (so far) in this project - am I correct? Could you also post whatever you have in your manifest?

Comment: (Really appreciate you taking the time to help btw)

Here is my implementation (I did try to create an activity with it)

http://www.blokey.net/misc/launcher.zip

Comment: Could you just copy and paste what you have in your manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`) and put it in your question (you can edit it). I'm at work and don't really want to download any files.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.matthieu.launcher"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity></activity>


    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: I just posted an answer - let me know if it makes sense and if you need more of an explanation.

Comment: ok did you want me to replace youractivityname and your label with anything else, I just pasted it into the manifest and it runs but I get a process has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: My Main.Java looks like this:

package com.matthieu.launcher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to change the `YourActivityName` to whatever your Activity's name is, and the label is just the title of the activity, and can be whatever you want.

Comment: Okay, so the name of your activity is `main`. So you can change the `YourActivityName` to `main`

Comment: I don't believe it, It WORKS!

You're a Genius!

Comment: and So damn fast and responsive

Comment: You I meant not the application  THANK YOU! (I'd been trying all day to figure it out!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to edit your manifest, so that the application knows which Activity to use when it first launches.

```
  <application>  
    <activity android:name=".YourActivityName" android:label="Your Label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
```