# How can I load an image from sdcard and use them to change the background to xml layout files?

Tags: android, xml, background, image

As I said in the title really, I have several screens in xml files and I use the them as in this application:

[Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969226/android-homescreen)

and I need to update several files in the first activity.  How do I read from the SDcard and put them as backgrounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Found the answer!  I am using a LinearLayout

```
   // Get External Storage Directory
    String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    LinearLayout li=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutid);
    li.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(newFile(sdcard,"/s1bg.jpg").getAbsolutePath()));
```