# How do I make a JQuery Slider-like feature on Android web app?

Tags: android, cordova

http://iphone.hohli.com/#docs/gallery.html, I need  slider like iphone jquery ui, for android .

Comment: may be this will help you :: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697799/android-how-can-i-make-my-page-slide-as-the-user-slides-finger-on-the-screen`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ViewPager` from the [Android Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) it does what you need. Or if you want to add an external component I suggest you to look at [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)