# swipe action with images in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How can i make my page slide as the user slides finger on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697799/android-how-can-i-make-my-page-slide-as-the-user-slides-finger-on-the-screen)

I have a set of images in drawables folder. I want to show it one by one according to user swipe action. I used **OnFling()** method to make this. But it displays the image only after the user finished the swipe. I want the image should be move with finger action. Can anyone suggest me the best idea? Thanks.

Comment: Related question: [Android: How can i make my page slide as the user slides finger on the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697799/android-how-can-i-make-my-page-slide-as-the-user-slides-finger-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the ViewPager, which is great for sideways swiping interfaces. Just create a fragment to hold each image.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

If you want to indicate which item the user is looking at, you can use the free ViewPagerIndicator

http://www.viewpagerindicator.com